# How to upload video files from WhatsApp Video Folder to Firebase on android device?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, local-storage, whatsapp

I want to create android application where should be a way to upload file on firebase. But Even after giving runtime permissions to storage, somehow Video is not being uploaded.

Here is my MainActivity.java file code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE = 0;
    private final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{
            "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
            "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
            "android.permission.INTERNET"
    };

    FireBaseHandler fb;

    private View mLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fb = new FireBaseHandler();

        mLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

        // Check if the permission has been granted
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission is already available, start camera preview
            Snackbar.make(mLayout,
                    "Permission_Available",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            fb.upload();
        } else {
            // Permission is missing and must be requested.
            requestPermission();
        }

        /*

        if(allPermissionsGranted()){
            fb.Upload(); //start upload if permission has been granted by user
        } else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
        }
        */
    }

    /*
    private boolean allPermissionsGranted(){

        for(String permission : REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    */

    private void requestPermission() {
        // Permission has not been granted and must be requested.
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
            // Display a SnackBar with cda button to request the missing permission.
            Snackbar.make(mLayout, "camera_access_required",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Request the permission
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE);
                }
            }).show();

        } else {
            Snackbar.make(mLayout, "Storage_unavailable", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Request the permission. The result will be received in onRequestPermissionResult().
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(onRequestPermissionsResult)
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE) {
            // Request for camera permission.
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission has been granted. Start camera preview Activity.
                Snackbar.make(mLayout, "camera_permission_granted",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                fb.upload();
            } else {
                // Permission request was denied.
                Snackbar.make(mLayout, "Storage_permission_denied",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
        // END_INCLUDE(onRequestPermissionsResult)
    }


    /*
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS){
            if(allPermissionsGranted()){
                fb.Upload();
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions not granted by the user.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                this.finish();
            }
        }
    }
    */
}
```

And here is code for uploading file

```
public class FireBaseHandler {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebase";

    FirebaseStorage storage; // = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    // Create a storage reference from our app
    StorageReference storageRef; // = storage.getReference();
    UploadTask uploadTask;

    public FireBaseHandler() {
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageRef = storage.getReference();
    }

    public void upload(){

        Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(getWhatsAppVideoDirectory()+"Abc.mp4"));
        StorageReference vidRef = storageRef.child("videos/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
        uploadTask = vidRef.putFile(file);

        // Register observers to listen for when the download is done or if it fails
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                Log.i(TAG,"onFailure");
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, etc.
                // ...
                Log.i(TAG,"onSuccess");
            }
        });

    }

    private String getWhatsAppVideoDirectory() {
        String folder_path = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                "/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/Sent/");

        //new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/WhatsApp/Media");

        return folder_path;
    }

}
```

Error is something like Access denied, Kindly tell me where am I doing it wrong way.

I have ran this code using Lower version of android that is 6.0.1 and it is working fine. I don't know if Google has some changes for newer android versions?

Comment: "Error is something like..." It's hard to help with an error without seeing the original error message. General descriptions or paraphrasings of the message are not usually helpful. Please edit your post to include the _exact_ wording of any error messages, including the full [stack trace](/a/23353174) of any exceptions, if applicable, as well as which line of code the stack trace points to. Please see [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I just found that you are not asking permission properly;

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE);
```

Here you are just asking for reading permission, Read permission is always true when you declare in manifest, but at runtime you should ask for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. So there is no meaning of above code, because it will be always true. You have to ask permission like this:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE);
```

Comment: But I just want to Read file or access file in order to upload that. I am not writing file now.